# 80C188 relocation register addressing mystery

Tags: embedded

I'm reverse-engineering an embedded system using the 80C188 and the way the relocation register (RELREG) is used mystifies me.

One of the first steps at initialization is to move the processor control registers by writing a new value to the RELREG.

By default, the RELREG has the value 20FFH which places the register block at the top of I/O space at address 0FFxxH.  The example given in the Intel app note describes writing the value of 1100H to the RELREG which then places the register block in memory space at 100xxH.  Clear enough.

However, in the system I am examining, the value is written is 1804H which I would expect to place the register block in memory space at the address 804xxH, yet the following writes to initialize the registers to operating values are all to 0F4xxH in memory space.  The processor is operating fine in the system so this is not a programming bug.

I am absolutely sure about these addresses as not only do I see them in the code itself on the EPROM but also in logic analyzer traces of code execution at startup.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: It would really help to see the code rather then your assertion of what the code does.  RELREG specifies the upper 12 bits of the PCB _physical address_, but the code will be written in terms of `segment:offset` addresses where the physical address will be `(segment << 4) + offset`.  A single physical address has 4096 possible seg:off addresses.  What is the value of the DS segment register? Regarding 02FFh, this has a _reserved_ bit set to 1; the data sheet says it should be 0.  How are you determining that that is the _default_ value?

Comment: You are correct about the addressing, I had forgotten a lot about that but a more thorough reading of the data sheet reminded me.  The setting of the reserved bit is a mystery to me as well.  The 02FFh default is specified in an AMD datasheet, and they also call the bit out as reserved.

Answer (score 1):

The address in the code is the *address offset* and must be combined with the appropriate segment register to map to a physical address.  The mapping is performed by:

```
(seg * 16) + offset
```

So if the `seg` were 7100h, then the `seg:off` address 7100:f400 refers to the physical address 80400h.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly correct, as I just this morning figured out.  There were two more MOV statements right after setting AX to 7100h which set DS and SS to that value so that indeed is what is going on.  I'm still curious how right after this there is a MOV of AL which seems to just be setting something to zero.  I'm using IDA and wish there was a way to get back into C which the higher level routines were written in, but that's another issue.